# Can I copy all users and passwords from a host machine to a docker running on it?

Tags: passwords, linux, docker

I want to create a docker on some machine with pre-configured users and passwords.

If I copy or mirror some files into the docker container, will the users be configured there as well, with their same old passwords?

If so - which files/folders do I need to copy?

Comment: What kind of password? login, application, database?

Comment: @ThoriumBR sorry, login password. I am installing ssh on the docker, and want the same password from the host to also be present inside for ssh connection.

Comment: If you copy `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/shadow` and `/etc/group`, users will be able to SSH in.

Comment: @ThoriumBR how can I do that? It seems [there is a problem copying ouside of the build context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132010/discussion-between-thoriumbr-and-gulzar).